# Local data access from JavaScript hosted in Winforms desktop application

Tags: winforms, desktop, hybrid

HTML/JS applications typically use HTTP APIs for data access.

Winform desktop applications typically use direct database access.

If an HTML/JS application is loaded inside a desktop application (for example, by using the [Winforms Browser Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/webbrowser-control-windows-forms)), how could the HTML/JS application access local data without using anything outside of the desktop application itself?

Comment: Never done anything like that but how i would start doing it is i would create communication line between HTML/JS app and Winform app, and then from online app send request to winform app and then when with event hander inside winform app catch if online app requested something, and if it is get data and send back information (json or your formatted string that you deserialize in your online app)

Comment: So it is something like multiplayer games communication is done between clients

Comment: Thanks, but the question is meant to use nothing outside of the desktop application itself.